# Как сделать custom splash screen на swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, экран

Делаю приложение у него 2 варианта дизайна, светлый и темный. Так вот я хочу чтобы например если день то запускался светлый дизайн а если ночь то темный. Но застрял в `Splash Screen`. Для него нельзя задать класс чтобы сделать там логику. Сделал так: удалил `Splash Screen` вместо него запускаю обычный `ViewController`, но при этом сперва появляется черный экран. Подскажите как сделать? Спасибо.

**Платформа iOS 7.*, swift 2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Splash Screen` придуман для того, чтобы "заговаривать зубы" пользователю, пока приложение грузится. Поэтому никакого кода там быть не может.
Соответсвенно, если вы его удалили, показывается "пусто", пока ваш `ViewController` грузится, потому что он часть приложения.

Правильно будет сделать нейтральный `Splash Screen`, а потом уже в коде как надо.